# Why Do I keep getting an import error when trying initiate the KNeighbors Classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am writing a simple Machine Learning model of the famous iris dataset on my Jupyter notebook but everytime i try to use the KNeighbors Classifier from the neighbors module i keep getting an error of

**KNeighborsClassifier' object is not callable**

here is my code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_new = np.array([[5, 2.9, 1, 0.2]])
predict = knn(X_new)
print(predict)


import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_new = np.array([[5, 2.9, 1, 0.2]])
predict = knn(X_new)
print(predict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `predict = knn(something)`, do `prediction = knn.predict(input)`.

`x = knn()` means instantiating a `KNeighborsClassifier` object, which you already created and not an import error.

Comment: Noted. I will try it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For people who searched this: you need to type 
`np.array([[5, 2.9, 1, 0.2]])` (2D array) not `np.array([5, 2.9, 1, 0.2])` (1D array).